# bluetooth is disabled on my ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lenovo

hello please help guys i cant enable blue tooth in my laptop

[image]

```
user@spider-king:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb; uname -a
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0621]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 005: ID 105b:e065  
    Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174f:14b2 Syntek 
    Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Linux spider-king 3.16.0-57-generic #77~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 23:20:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Is this a elementary theme or elementary os itself?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: Your BT device is `105b:e065`.

Comment: @markkirby It is not distro dependent.

Comment: How do you know it is Elementary? By the theme? It is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use hardware buttons to enable ...
Might be fn+F2 or F3 or F* depending on your laptop

Comment: no dude its not working......

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth might be soft locked. 
To check that run

```
rfkill list
```

If you see your Bluetooth being soft blocked issue

```
sudo rfkill unblock *<device id>*
```

or `sudo rfkill unblock all`/`sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`